# why is tinymce not showing up on a dynamically added text area

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

Guys recently i finished a infinite scroll to one of my projects using jquery, php and mysql. After creating that i face the problem of tinymce editor not binding to the dynamically generated textarea. What should i do? here is the code for tinymce editor:

```
    tinymce.init({
    menubar:false,
    forced_root_block : "",
    selector: "textarea#wall_edit_1",
     entities : '160,nbsp,162,cent,8364,euro,163,pound',
    theme: "modern",
    resize: false,
    height: 200,
    plugins: [
         " autolink link image preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker",
         "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
         "save table contextmenu directionality emoticons paste textcolor"
   ],
   content_css: "css/content.css",
   toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | l      ink image | print preview media fullpage |  emoticons", 
   style_formats: [
        {title: 'Bold text', inline: 'b'},
      //  {title: 'Red text', inline: 'span', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
        {title: 'Header', block: 'h1'},
        {title: 'Example 1', inline: 'span', classes: 'example1'},
        {title: 'Example 2', inline: 'span', classes: 'example2'},
        {title: 'Table styles'},
        {title: 'Table row 1', selector: 'tr', classes: 'tablerow1'}
    ]
    });
```

here is the php code that dynamically generates the textarea while using the infinite scroll feature in jquery:

```
if ($author==$_SESSION['uname'] || $account_name==$_SESSION['uname']) {
                $statusdeletebutton='<li>'
                           . '<a  type="'.$updateid.'" class="btn delete_4_session hidden_text_delete_'.$updateid.' glyphicon glyphicon-trash delete_status_btn" title="Delete this status and its replies">Remove</a></li>';
                $edit_btn='<li>'
                        . '<a attr="'.$updateid.'" type="'.$updateid.'" class="btn edit_4_session hidden_text_edit glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" title="Edit this status" >Edit</a></li>';
                $statusui_edit="<div type='".$updateid."' class='hidden_edit_4_session session_editor".$updateid." jumbotron'>"
            . "<a type='".$updateid."' class='btn pull-right close_edit' title='Close without editing'>Close X</a>"
            . "<input type='text' class='form-control title_s_edit title_s_".$updateid."' name='status_title' value='".html_entity_decode($title)."' placeholder='Title' >"
            . "<span>&nbsp;</span>"
            . "<textarea id='wall_edit_1' type='".$updateid."' rows='5' cols='50'  class='session_edit text_value_".$updateid."' wrap='hard' placeholder='whats up ".$session_uname."'>
             ".html_entity_decode($data1)."</textarea><br>"
            . "<button style='float:right;' value='".$updateid."' type='a' class='btn btn-warning btn btn-large btn-lg post-s-edit'>Update</button></div>" ;

                }else{
                    $statusdeletebutton="";
                    $edit_btn="<li class='posted'>You are not the owner of this Post</li>";
                    $statusui_edit="";
                }

       echo $statusui_edit.''. $hidden_text.'<div attr="'.$updateid.'" type="'.$updateid.'" class="statusboxes status_'.$updateid.'  jumbotron">'
                        . '<h3 class="pull-left title">'
                        . '<div id="'.$updateid.'" class="title_s_2copy posted" value="'.html_entity_decode($title).'">'.html_entity_decode($title).'</div></h3>'
                        . '<span class="pull-right">'
                        . '<div class="dropdown">'
                        . '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"  >'
                        . '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button>'
                        . '<ul class="dropdown-menu">'
                         .$edit_btn .' '. $statusdeletebutton .'</ul></div></span><br><hr>'
                        . '<legend><span style="font-size: 13.5px;" class=" data_s_2copy" type="'.$updateid.'" >'
                        . html_entity_decode($data1).'</span></legend><b class="posted"><small>Posted by:-  <a href="home.php?u='.$author.'"><img src="'.$feed_pic.'" height="20px" width="20px"> '.$author.   '</a>   '.$datemade.'</small></b>'
                        . '<br><legend>'.$like.' | '.$unlike. ' | '.$share_button.'<h4><a id="'.$updateid.'" class="btn collap-btn">Comments</a></h4></legend>';
```

here is the place where i init it in jquery:

```
 $(document).on("click",".hidden_text_edit",function(){
    var id=$(this).attr("type");

    $(".session_editor"+id).removeClass("hide");
    $(".session_editor"+id).show(function(){
        tinymce.init({
    menubar:false,
    forced_root_block : "",
    selector: "textarea#wall_edit_1",
     entities : '160,nbsp,162,cent,8364,euro,163,pound',
    theme: "modern",
    resize: false,
    height: 200,
    plugins: [
         " autolink link image preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker",
         "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
         "save table contextmenu directionality emoticons paste textcolor"
   ],
   content_css: "css/content.css",
   toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | l      ink image | print preview media fullpage |  emoticons", 
   style_formats: [
        {title: 'Bold text', inline: 'b'},
      //  {title: 'Red text', inline: 'span', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
        {title: 'Header', block: 'h1'},
        {title: 'Example 1', inline: 'span', classes: 'example1'},
        {title: 'Example 2', inline: 'span', classes: 'example2'},
        {title: 'Table styles'},
        {title: 'Table row 1', selector: 'tr', classes: 'tablerow1'}
    ]
    });
    });

    $(".status_"+id).hide();

    });
```

Comment: you just check id  "wall_edit_1" is unique in DOM

Comment: @AnishChandran i changed the id to a dynamic one still not working :(

Comment: @srivastava any ideas on this bro

Comment: check   tinymce.init code "selector: "textarea#wall_edit_1" , here you specify the static id not dynamic

Comment: hurray i got it right this time. @AnishChandran

Answer (score 0):

Try to Select CSS class rather than ID,
Or you can change generated id to select.

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '.mytextarea',
    plugins: 'a11ychecker advcode.....all plugins goes here.
});
```

I also didn't found a simple TinyMCE function to call directly if needed.
We just need to call everything again, if we did in past too.